# Move the first four list items to the end of the list

Tags: javascript, list, optimization

So I have a list with several `<li>` elements,

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
    <li>h</li>
</ul>
```

The context is I want to re-use `li` elements across a 1,000 memory intensive list for iOS. The objective is to display first 4 elements, the rest 4 are hidden, the container displays 4 items at a time.

On scroll (button tap), I'm going to animate the list and slide in the other 4, and at the end of the animation, move the first 4 `li` items towards the end of the list (and then reset the position to `left: 0` for the `ul`)

My question is how I can get a hold of first elements and add them towards the end in plain javascript. (I'm handling animation through TweenLite)

**Bonus:** if you can suggest some better optimization techniques or library when it comes to display numerous elements.

Comment: just to be clear you want to re-use list item values or just list elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it in pure JS. You can access the `li` elements with [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the first 4. Then you can add them to the `ul` by popping them from the array with [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and putting them on the end with [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

[Working JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/e131qewx/3/)

```
function moveEle() {
    var ele = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    //getElementsByTagName() returns a collection, so we bind the slice function to it
    var fourEle = Array.prototype.slice.call( ele, 0, 4);
    var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

    while (fourEle.length > 0) {
        //Pop the first element from the 4 and add it to the end
        ul.appendChild(fourEle.shift());
    }
}

document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = moveEle;
```

Edit:
To add an element  at the beginning, use `insertBefore()` instead of `appendChild()`. You'd also use `pop()` instead of `shift()` in the above example.

Comment: is there a function to add to the beginning of the ul list?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @Parker

Answer (score 1):

You can get a NodeList to iterate through by using getElementsByTagName(), like this:

```
var list = document.getElementById("yourUlItem").getElementsByTagName("li");
```

You can then use Array `slice` function to catch all the subsets you need by preserving the right index in order to catch the sets :

```
var firstFour = list.slice(0, 3);
```

Comment: please add some more code to remove them from the list and add towards the end using plain javascript (no jquery)