# How would I move an li to the bottom of a ul?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to move an li to the bottom of a ul, but can't figure out how to do it. I've looked at [Move the first four list items to the end of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210664/move-the-first-four-list-items-to-the-end-of-the-list) and [Move items in Ul Li up and down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046590/move-items-in-ul-li-up-and-down) (this one didn't work because it was JQuery and I'm trying to use JS) , but neither worked. I've even tried to remove the li and add it back afterward, but couldn't get onclick to work.

Here is the ul:

```html
<ul class="role_box_roles" id="rbroles">
    <li class="role_box_role" style="border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
        <button class="role_remove_button" type="button" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">-</button>
        <span>Staff</span>
    </li>
    <li id="plusbutton"><button class="role_add" type="button" onclick="show_options()">+</button></li>
</ul>
```

The li that I need to keep at the bottom is the one with the "plusbutton" id. (I say keep in place because whenever I add a new item to the ul, it gets added below the "plusbutton" li)

The add_option function:

```js
function add_option(optionname) {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var removeButton = document.createElement("button");
    var optionSpan = document.createElement("span");

    listItem.className = "role_box_role";
    listItem.style = "border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);";

    //removeButton.type = "button";
    removeButton.innerText = "-";
    removeButton.className = "role_remove_button";
    removeButton.style = "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);";

    optionSpan.innerText = optionname;

    listUl = document.getElementById("rbroles");
    listUl.appendChild(listItem);
    listItem.appendChild(removeButton);
    listItem.appendChild(optionSpan);
}
```

Comment: how are you adding the `li` please share that script also ?

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with how you insert new ones. look into how `insertBefore()` works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

Comment: @AlwaysHelping there you go.

Comment: @charlietfl  I've tried insertBefore(), but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: How do you call this `add_option()` function - on a button click ?

Comment: yes `onclick="add_option('option name')"`

Comment: Oh, wait. I read more in the developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore that charlietfl linked and realized that I was defining the plusbutton list as the insertBefore version (the sorted version). When I fixed it I got the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use [before()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/before) to do that as well by `referencing` the `node` (li) you want to add before it to.

**Live Demo:**

```js
function add_option(optionname) {
  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  var removeButton = document.createElement("button");
  var optionSpan = document.createElement("span");

  listItem.className = "role_box_role";
  listItem.style = "border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);";

  //removeButton.type = "button";
  removeButton.innerText = "-";
  removeButton.className = "role_remove_button";
  removeButton.style = "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);";

  optionSpan.innerText = optionname;
  listItem.appendChild(removeButton);
  listItem.appendChild(optionSpan);
 
  // Get reference node
  var referenceNode = document.querySelector('#plusbutton');

  // Add the new node before the reference node
  referenceNode.before(listItem);
}
```

```html
<ul class="role_box_roles" id="rbroles">
  <li class="role_box_role" style="border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
    <button class="role_remove_button" type="button" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">-</button>
    <span>Staff</span>
  </li>
  <li id="plusbutton"><button class="role_add" type="button" onclick="show_options()">+</button></li>
</ul>


<button onclick="add_option('Blah')">
  Add
</button>
```

Comment: I was also able to get it to work with `listpb = listUl.insertBefore(listpb, null)` . I wasn't able to get this to work before because I didn't define listpb as the ordered one (It was  just `listUl.insertBefore(listpb, null)`).

Comment: @User-92 Nice. You can either one of function. `InsertBefore` expects two `arguments` once the reference second the new node. While in your case you just wanted to add before the `plusbutton` so using `before()` would be ideal but its up to what suits you best ;)